# How to insert a value into a json array via postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this sql query:

```
SELECT array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(t))) 
FROM (SELECT rendered_json, city_id FROM hotels WHERE id IN (1)) as t
```

and after execution i get:

```
"[{rendered_json:{address:Den Texstraat 16,city:Amsterdam,hotel_class:2,
currencycode:EUR,hotel_id:10003,hoteltype_id:14,latitude:52.3588347328288,
longitude:4.89386737346649,name:Asterisk Hotel,review_score:7.4,min_price:0.0},
city_id:-2140479}]"
```

But i want to remove the field `rendered_json` and get

```
"[{address:Den Texstraat 16,city:Amsterdam,hotel_class:2,
 currencycode:EUR,hotel_id:10003,hoteltype_id:14,latitude:52.3588347328288,
longitude:4.89386737346649,name:Asterisk Hotel,review_score:7.4,min_price:0.0,
city_id:-2140479}]"
```

If my query:

```
SELECT array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(t)::json->'rendered_json')) 
FROM (SELECT rendered_json, city_id FROM hotels WHERE id IN (1)) as t
```

then i lose field `city_id`.

How to build the query for my requirements? Is it possible?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that rendered_json is redundant and inflexible.  Either it will fall out of date as rows get updated, or you have a lot of triggers which will slow down updates and inserts.  Rather than trying to modify it, which would seem to defeat the point of having it cached, get rid of it (or ignore it) and build the JSON yourself.

```
SELECT row_to_json(hotel_data)
FROM   (
    SELECT address, city, hotel_class, currencycode, hotel_id,
           hoteltype_id, latitude, longitude, name, review_score,
           min_price, city_id
    FROM   hotels
    WHERE  id = 1
) as hotel_data
```

(I apologize for any syntax mistakes, I don't have PG handy to test it)

If generating this gets expensive, do the normal query optimizations and if that doesn't work [consider a query cache](http://www.postgresql.org/about/news/1296/).

Comment: Thanks. This is works! But too much writing... Actually there is much more fields inside `rendered_json` (I cut when created the question)

Comment: @DmitryKrakosevich It's only too much writing if you're writing it more than once.  If you're writing it more than once, write a program to do it for you.